# Does Cake Pattern always need to be implemented as inner class?

Tags: scala, oop, dependency-injection, cake-pattern

I just read [Jonas' well-known article about Cake Pattern](http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/), for a class like:

```
class UserRepository {
  def authenticate(user: User): User = {
    println("authenticating user: " + user)
    user
   }
  def create(user: User) = println("creating user: " + user)
  def delete(user: User) = println("deleting user: " + user)
}
```

According to that article, for using Cake Pattern, it need to be wrapped as inner class in a trait, e.g.:

```
trait UserRepositoryComponent {
  val userRepository: UserRepository

  class UserRepository {
    ...
  }
}
```

So I am wondering:

1. Is this the only way to achieve Cake Pattern?
2. If so, does it mean class such as `UserRepository` has to be designed with Cake Pattern in mind at the time it's designed (so that they can be wrapped in a trait)?
3. If the answer is yes, is there any common practice that can include a class that is not defined within a wrapper into a design based on Cake Pattern?
   (something similar to adapter in concept)

Comment: If this question purely about terminology/definitions or is there any practical component in this question?

Comment: The pattern you show there of designing your classes upfront in that specific way is called the cake pattern. So this feels a bit like asking whether you need to implement the cake pattern to achieve Cake Pattern.

Comment: Hi @SergGr, I think it's both. The first part of my question is for making sure that I understand the definition of Cake Pattern correctly, i.e. does Cake Pattern always require wrapping class such as `UserRepositoryComponent` at the time the class is defined? The second part is, if it is how I understood it, in practical usage, how do people cope with the limitation that I mentioned, i.e. what if I need to use a third party class that is not wrapped in component? Thanks

Comment: @Jasper-M, so what you meant is I did understand cake pattern correctly, i.e. cake pattern always require wrapping class at the time it's defined? Then I am wondering, what is the common practice for handling the situation when I need to incorporate a third party class into my classes when it's not wrapped in component?